# Why isn't this 100% height working?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
html { height: 100%; }

body { min-height: 100%; margin: 0; }

#test { height: 100%;  background: red; width: 50px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="test">test</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k176a1xc/1/

Why doesn't #test have a 100% height?

Comment: Replace `body { min-height: 100%; margin: 0; }` by `body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

Because body `min-height` should be defined as `height` :

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/p7vn7vrj/**
The `body` `min-height` percentage is a `min-height` of "nothing", because there is no `height` to calculate the `min-height` percentage against. Therefore `#test` `height` will be the same as body `min-height`, which is not set.

the CSS hierarchy is

```
height 
   min-height
   max-height
     height (child)
       min-height
       max-height
```

and so on

Comment: why do all the tutorials on giving the div a 100% height use min-height on the body then?

Comment: @user1807782, I dont know. Have you read about it on w3fools? Give a link as example.